# Terraform AWS Event Source Mapping Issue - Self Managed Kafka

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

My company has some Kafka servers on prem that we would like to add as an event source for Lambda.

I have everything set up correctly and I can build a single ESM via terraforms `aws_lambda_event_source_mapping`

The problem is.. I am trying to build in multiple dev environments.. dev1, dev2, dev3.. etc..

I seems there is a probalem in terraform where .. it will build an ESM.. but then when it tries to build another one.. it throws the following error:

```
creating Lambda Event Source Mapping (Self-Managed Apache Kafka): ResourceConflictException: An event source mapping with event source (<our servers...>), selfM
anagedKafkaEventSourceConfig.consumerGroupId ("<the consumer group>") already exists. Please update or delete the existing mapping with UUID <the UUID>
```

They are all the same event source.. except there is a different Kafka topic associated with each one to match each dev environment. The terraform looks like this:

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "topic_mapping_1" {
  function_name     = var.function_name
  starting_position = var.starting_position // tried by LATEST and TRIM_HORIZON
  batch_size        = var.batch_size // 1
  enabled           = var.kafka_enabled //  true
  topics            = [var.topic_1_name[var.env]]

  self_managed_event_source {
    endpoints = {
      KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = var.kafka_endpoints
    }
  }
  self_managed_kafka_event_source_config {
    consumer_group_id = var.consumer_group_id
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "topic_mapping_2" {
  function_name     = var.function_name
  starting_position = var.starting_position // tried by LATEST and TRIM_HORIZON
  batch_size        = var.batch_size // 1
  enabled           = var.kafka_enabled //  true
  topics            = [var.topic_2_name[var.env]]

  self_managed_event_source {
    endpoints = {
      KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = var.kafka_endpoints
    }
  }
  self_managed_kafka_event_source_config {
    consumer_group_id = var.consumer_group_id
  }
}
```

Is there something else i need to do? Has anyone experienced this before?

I have tried building topics separately. I have tried switching from LATEST to TRIM_HORIZON as I so there was a bug in CloudFormation (wasn't sure if that was also true for Terraform)

I have tried using the CLI to delete the UUID mentioned and rebuild.. but it just creates a new ESM UUID and that one now blocks the others.

Answer (score 1):

In AWS Lambda, each event source mapping is identified by a unique combination of the event source (e.g., your Kafka server) and the consumer_group_id.
modify your Terraform configuration to include a unique identifier for each development environment in the consumer_group_id. This ensures that each ESM is considered unique by AWS.

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "topic_mapping_1" {
  ...
  self_managed_kafka_event_source_config {
    consumer_group_id = "${var.consumer_group_id}-${var.env}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this consumer_group_id get sent to kafka for commits? I have a consumer group that was granted access.. example.. my-consumer-group has access to devTopic1, devTopic2, devTopic3... etc.. I would want to send my-consumer-group to each of those.. or I guess i would need to create a consumer group for each dev environment...? (i really wanted to avoid that)  EDITL I will also add that sometimes it DOES add both event source mappings.. and sometimes it doesn't. That's why I'm thinking it's a bug.

Comment: yes, one consumer group for each environment would be needed